# React Native positioning text on multi picker

Tags: ios, css, iphone, react-native, flexbox

I have three pickers on screen and I am trying to align text using position absolute and setting top and left values. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Khek.png)

Position absolute won't work for different screen sizes as it hard coded. Any suggestions please?

I am trying to achieve timer style layout in iPhone [iPhone timer screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYYNW.png)

Code excerpt below

```
<View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.pickerValueA}
          onValueChange={(value) => {
            this.setState({ pickerValueA: value });
          }}
          itemStyle={{ color: 'black' }}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="30" value="30" />
          <Picker.Item label="31" value="31" />
          <Picker.Item label="32" value="32" />
          <Picker.Item label="33" value="33" />
          <Picker.Item label="34" value="34" />
          <Picker.Item label="35" value="35" />
        </Picker>
      </View>

    </View>
    <Text
      style={{
        textAlign: 'center',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 95,
        left: 90,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20
      }}
    >
      Text 1
    </Text>
```

Comment: Please provide the rendered HTML content.

Comment: @GibinEalias Thanks for your reply. The screenshot is at the following link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Khek.png

Comment: I mean to say the HTML code

Comment: Sorry, It's React Native App so the JSX above is the code...